# Eclipse in the meanwhile a pain? Validations kill productivity => eclipse hangs => no tracing?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, validation, trace

I am a really long user of eclipse, but eclipse seems to loose more and more velocity and the ease of analysing problems in eclipse.
Or am I unable to use eclipse anymore?

If eclipse starts to hang in our case, the validation get stuck at 59% of a folder. I am not able to figure out:

- which validator is hanging?
- which files are the issue?

Does eclipse do **not** provide any tracing mechanism for such cases? Have a developer in eclipse to ask his crystal bowl what is right now done?

To some contexts of the projects.
We are using Java, along with javascript. Javascript with NPM (node_modules) and bower (bower_components), so we are getting a huge mass on 3rd Party deps, which may ore may not be the issue.
We run on eclipse 4.4.1

So beside of disabling the validations, how can someone analyze which files are the problematic once?
I hope the developers of the validators have provided tracing mechanisms for such cases?

The only thing I can see and reproduce, eclipse hangs at 59% on a project on the folder /app, which is our js, css and html area.

Hope someone can help me out of the dark?